# How can I use multiple subqueries in a WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Just starting to learn SQL and I can't find the answer after a million google searches.

```
SELECT name, population FROM world
WHERE population > (SELECT population FROM world 
WHERE name = 'Canada');
WHERE population < (SELECT population FROM world
WHERE name = 'Poland');
```

I know you could use "Joins" or something else like that but using subqueries how would I do this? Basically, I'm looking for populations that are greater than Canada's but less than Poland's.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. Just need an AND instead of a semi-colon.

```
SELECT name, population FROM world
WHERE population > (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Canada')
AND
WHERE population < (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Poland');
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, population FROM world
WHERE population > (SELECT population FROM world 
WHERE name = 'Canada') AND 
population < (SELECT population FROM world
WHERE name = 'Poland');
```

Comment: I'm not sure either, so I balanced it out :P

Comment: Can`t believe people downvotes for no reason.Anyway Thanks tsHunter:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AND`.

```
SELECT name, population FROM world
WHERE population > (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Canada')
AND population < (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Poland');
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks sir. I had it like this originally with no luck, must've been off a bit.

Comment: @user3521314 - np! If it answers your question you should +1 and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on basic syntax.

Try

`SELECT name, population FROM world
    WHERE population > (SELECT population FROM world 
     WHERE name = 'Canada');
    AND population < (SELECT population FROM world
     WHERE name = 'Poland');`